# how to concatenate an int parameter in an href in a MVC view

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have the following `div` in a `MVC` view

```
<div>
      <span style="min-width: 105px; max-width: 120px; display: inline-block;">Images Available:</span>
       <span><b></b></span>
</div>
```

In the second `span` I would like to add an reference to an `aspx` page that requires an `id` passed to in which is an `int` data type.

I thought of doing something like this:

```
<span><b><a href="~/pages/inventory/_inventory_image.aspx?qinventory_id=" + Model.InventoryId</a></b></span>
```

That half works by giving me the page url but no InventoryId.

I also tried ampersand which I know is for `string` values also to no avail

Could someone help a brother out? :-)

Comment: I think you need to put the @ symbol. @Model.InventoryId and also put " after the InventoryId.

Comment: Any particular reason to not just use the [UrlHelper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.aspx) to generate the URL?

Comment: @TiesonT.  No particular reason just following suit with the existing code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass `Model.InventoryId` with the quotes.

```
<span><b><a href="~/pages/inventory/_inventory_image.aspx?qinventory_id=@Model.InventoryId"></a></b></span>
```